# Angular 1.3 getter setter ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im starting to learn the new features in angular 1.3, and i don`t understanding this feature, what he does and what is benefit?

Comment: This will be a good place to read the benefits and the basic usage of ngModel
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel

Comment: I dont mean all ngModel im only mean the new feature of getter setter, and i read the docs and dont understand thats why im asking here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the angular documentation, they state that the `getter/setter` function can be helpful because it's sometimes "useful to use this for models that have an internal representation that's different than what the model exposes to the view."

That being said, the getter/setter method just attaches itself to the `ngModel` of whatever DOM element it is connected to, and either sets, or gets the current model value.

The JavaScript equivalent to this would be something like:

```
this.getValue = function() { return this.value; }:

this.setValue = function(val) { this.value = val; };

document.getElementById('el').addEventListener('change', setValue );
```